# Design to convert objects from ClassType to String and getting it back

Tags: java, oop

I am getting objects of different type as a parameter into different service APIs.
Example APIs:

```
void API1(Object1 obj1);
void API2(Object2 obj2);
```

On receiving the APIs, I convert objects to JSON type and store at a specified location. Another poller polls for the stored location and tried to convert it to object type using `Gson`.

One way, I can think of is to create a `RequestWrapper` containing objects of all type (ex. Object1, Object2 etc.) and populate the correct variable while storing the data.

On receiving end, we can convert the object to RequestWrapper object and check for the populated object.

As you can see, this requires additional object of 20+ variables and most of them will be null. Also, multiple if-else checks while converting it to correct type.

What could be the best way to achieve this in object oriented way, if any?

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level, it would seem there are two approaches to getting the data type of a serialized object that came from a client.

1. Make the client tell you.
2. Figure it out for yourself.

A couple ways I can think of to make the client tell you:

1. Add an API for each distinct data type.

   ```
   void API1(Foo obj1);
   void API1(Bar obj2);
   void API2(Foo obj1);
   void API2(Bar obj2);
   ```
2. Require the client to include it in the serialized form.

   ```
   {"class":"myPackage.MyClass"}
   ```

A couple ways I can think of to figure it out for yourself:

1. Pre-parse the JSON string for some unique identifier (i.e. determine the type before deserializing).

   ```
   if (jsonString.contains("foo")) {
       Foo foo = gsonInstance.fromJson(jsonString, Foo.class);
   }
   ```
2. The aforementioned wrapper approach (i.e. determine the type after deserializing).

I don't know that any approach is particularly object oriented, but then how object oriented is serialized data to begin with?